# Android/Retrofit: Best way of refreshing token every thirty minutes when server won't return 401 error on expiration?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, token

My app's API does not return 401 errors-or indicate any sort of a problem-if either of the two tokens used to access it have reached the end of their lifespans. For whatever reason, the backend devs have requested that I manually refresh the tokens every 15 and 30 minutes respectively from the time that the app's session begins. This means I can't use Authenticator since there is no error code I can manipulate, and I'm not sure how to use Interceptor to force an error code on a response after timeout.

What is the best way of setting timers for 15 and 30 minutes to fire the refresh requests whenever I need to?

Comment: "My app's API does not return 401 errors if the token is expired" -- then what *does* it do? "automatically refresh the token every thirty minutes" -- thirty minutes from what? (previous request? top and bottom of every hour? something else?) and using whose clock? (server time? client time?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your error status code to 401 by adding `networkIntrceptor` and proceed as usual. I didn't try this but I'm pretty sure that it's possible.